# Custom merge driver not working in GitKraken

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, gitkraken, three-way-merge

I am trying to use *merge-po* driver https://github.com/mezis/git-whistles#merge-po for smart merging gettext generated translation *.po files.

Driver works just fine in CLI (merged without conflicts) but GitKraken completely ignores custom merge driver settings (tried both local and global) and generates unnecessary conflicts. Is there any way how to use custom merge drivers directly in GitKraken?

**~/.gitconfig**

```
[push]
    followTags = true
[core]
    attributesfile = ~/.gitattributes
[merge "pofile"]
    name = custom merge driver for gettext po files
    driver = git merge-po %O %A %B
```

**~/.gitattributes**

```
*.po merge=pofile
*.pot merge=pofile
```

Comment: GitKraken mostly uses its own build-in git along with its' config. That's why your current config is ignored. You can, however, set the  ´Path to sh` in Settings->General. This allows GitKraken to run previously specified hooks, but I don't know it it helps with the config.

Comment: I don't see any option 'Path to sh' in Preferences->General section. It is noteworthy that I am not using pro version of GitKraken.

Comment: Hmm. May be a pro feature. Which OS are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS